# Adding an OR to if/else statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I was wondering if there was a way I could make an if statement with multiple 'true' conditions, for example, if `cat="red"` or `cat="blue"` then it would run and proceed. I know you can do `&&` but that requires both things to be true, and I am looking more for an either or. Anyone know what I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the || operator. It's much like && but represents "OR" rather than "AND"

Comment: Do you have a link to some official documentation?